# Another verb for the sounds letters make

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

I have a few dictionaries that state "prononcer" as a word in use, but that seems much too formal, especially when I'm trying to use something equivalent to "the letter says" which is something used with kids. Is this maybe not really taught to francophone kids as often? Or do I just need to find new dictionaries?

Answer (score 6):

*Prononcer* is just fine even with kids but beware that unlike with English, you cannot say that a letter **say** or **read** something. The pronominal (a.k.a reflexive) form (*se prononcer*, *se lit*) is mandatory here, e.g.:

> *La lettre C est une consonne qui **se prononce** soit comme un S, soit comme un K suivant la voyelle qui suit. Les deux lettres AU **se prononcent** comme un O*.

The pronominal form is mandatory when letters, syllables, words and sentences are the subject of *prononcer*, but otherwise, the direct, non-reflexive form is used:

> *Les anglais n'arrivent pas à **prononcer** correctement les mots serrurier et croissant*.

*Vocaliser* would be less understood, especially by kids, and might also be used to describe singers exercising their voice. *Articuler* is specialized, and is more about the quality of the pronunciation than the pronunciation itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Se prononcer** is the best translation

However, in a less formal style (similar to "the letter says"), you could also use :

**se dire**

```
La lettre C se dit 'K' sauf devant y, i ou e.
```